# Detect muted conversations

Tags: telethon

Is it possible to differentiate between muted and unmuted conversations using the library? I could not find any information in the entity object or the dialog ( Chat / Channel ) object. Or is there a separate request to get the muted conversation? I could not find any mention about muted conversations in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access notifications settings information about `Users`, `Chats` and `Channels` you have to request their `FullEntity`. This can be done invoking [`GetFullUser`](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=GetFullUser), [`GetFullChat`](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=GetFullChat) and [`GetFullChannel`](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=GetFullChannel) respectively.

I'll leave here an example working with `Users`

```
result = await userbot(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
    id='username'
))
print(result.notify_settings)
```

So basically once you have the  `FullEntity`, use `.notify_settings` to access the `PeerNotifySettings` object that contains the informations you are looking for.

Take a look at the [Telethon Docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html#full-entities) for further informations.